# What is the name of a triangular structure which has 2r-1 elements in the r-th row?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

A triangular array is an array where the r-th row has r elements - the Pascal's triangle is the most common example of this structure and has been well analysed.

What is the name of the structure that has 2r-1 elements in the r-th row? This is a structure I use in a math game that I have created, and I wish to analyze that structure for the purposes of generating puzzles, grading puzzles, laying out constraints, etc. If there is prior information about this structure, it would provide a good starting point for me.

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this structure has a specific name in terms of geometric objects. But if you consider $r$ as discrete values on the $x$-axis and the number of elements in the $r$-th row as values of the function
$$f(r) = 2r -1$$
you get the lattice of a step function. Maybe that helps you?

Comment: It's useful to know. However, I don't know how to use that to model my game - my game has similarities to Sudoku (though Sudoku is far more constrained than my game), and I am trying to model my game the way the Sudoku/math/computer science community has modeled Sudoku.

Comment: Maybe you can describe your game in a more detailed way, since you haven't provided much information about what you mean by structure and what you want with all this. :-)

Comment: I have added a separate related question that describes the game at [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564008/how-do-i-grade-the-complexity-of-the-below-math-puzzle-game). I have more questions (solvability, efficient solution, generating levels, etc.), but then bundling them together may be too broad for this forum. Another link that describes the game in detail with pictures is [link](http://qr.ae/NLrtk).