# How do I grade the complexity of the below math puzzle game?

Tags: computational-complexity, algorithmic-game-theory

The game (I built it, and it is currently live on mobile) involves solving a pascal's triangle like grid of numbers with operators between the numbers - an example with 3 rows is:

```
      n1
   n2 o1 n3
n4 o2 n5 o3 n6
```

The goal of the game is simple: Each number in all the rows except the bottom row should be the result of the binary expression right below it. So, in the above example, the solution is achieved if n1 = n2 o1 n3; n2 = n4 o2 n5; and n3 = n5 o3 n6.

In the problem grid, numbers are swapped with each other and operators are swapped with each other till the solution is reached. In each problem, 0 or more items (numbers and operators) are fixed.

The actual game has 3 to 5 rows (since <3 is too easy, and >5 doesn't fit easily on a mobile device) of two digit numbers, and the only operators are +, -, * and ÷.
A problem is described by an array of numbers, an array of operators and the indices of fixed items in each array.

Given a game (a shuffled grid with hints) as described above, how do I grade it based on complexity?

A detailed description of the game, with screenshots, etc. (on Android and iOS - called Sumurai) is provided at http://qr.ae/NLrtk

Comment: What complexity-grading scheme are you trying to fit this game into? I can't imagine you really mean computational complexity (a la P vs NP), since you're only talking about games of fixed size.

Comment: The real goal is to be able to generate puzzles given a level (easy, medium, hard, etc.) such that an easy puzzle is always easier to solve than a medium, a medium is always easier to solve than a hard, etc. Towards that end, I want to solve the subproblem, where given two randomly generated puzzles, I can affix a complexity value to each such that the easier one always has a lower complexity value.

Comment: I just downloaded the lite version of your game.  How are you currently determining difficulty, because some "easy" puzzles have three rows, while some have four rows?

Comment: Thanks. I currently have a combination of number of rows and number of hints (which are the grayed items) that make each level. So, an easier level will have more hints for a given number of rows than the harder levels. The "Easy" level has only 3 or 4 rows, while medium (and higher levels in the Pro version) have 3, 4 or 5 rows with lesser and lesser hints shown for each level.

Comment: BTW, I am considering an alternate algorithm where the minimum number of swaps used to go from the puzzle to the solution is used to determine the complexity. So, for example, the Easy level may only have 2-3 numbers/operators out of place (irrespective of number of rows), whereas harder levels will have more items in the wrong place. Am still not sure that is the right approach, but it may be better than what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second approach is good. The minimum number of swaps is a measure of complexity in the symmetric group that is frequently used, and correlates directly with gameplay length.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I am going with:

For generating puzzles, I use specific numbers of swaps - lesser for easier levels and more for harder levels.

For evaluating a given puzzle (to enable sharing of puzzles), I will first solve the puzzle, and then use [the Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Ruby) -  to determine distance between the puzzle and the solution, and use that as a measure of complexity.